# Finding groups of k disjoint rows in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, combinatorics

**Problem statement:** Let `S` be a set of integers, e.g. `S = {1,2,...,12}`. `M` is an integer matrix whose rows can be viewed as subsets of `S`, whose length divides the number of elements of `S`, in particular every row of `M` contains only distinct elements/integers. I am trying to produce Matlab code that can identify all groups of disjoint rows of `M` whose set-theoretic union gives  `S`(i.e. a partition of `S` in subsets with a fixed size) and return each such group as a matrix.

**Example:** `A = [1 2 5 6; 3 4 11 12; 9 10 7 8]` is a partition of `S`, whereas `B = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 1 5 9 12]` is not a partition of `S` (since the last row is not disjoint with the previous 3).

**Order of magnitude:** Typically, `M` would have ~ 500 000 rows and `S` would have up to 100 elements.

**Approach so far:** let `m = size(M,1)`, `n = size(M,2)` (size of the partitioning subsets), `s = |S|` (size of the set to be partitioned) and `k = s/n` (number of necessary disjoint rows to form a partition - you can assume `s = 0 mod n`, so the problem is well-defined). Note that, in order to establish such a partition, it suffices to check for disjointness of the rows and that there are exactly `k` many of them.

For `j = 1:(m-k+1)`, I observe `ind = (sum(ismember(M((j+1):m,:),M(j,:)),2)==0)`, which gives me the column of indices of the rows after `M(j,:)` that are also disjoint with it. Then I create `2 x n` matrices by combining `M(j,:)` with each of those rows. After that I'd like to repeat the `ismember()`routine with all these new `2 x n` matrices and keep repeating until I get `k x n`matrices. Which is probably all nice and dandy, but it's also where I stumble, because, for one, the number of `for`-routines depends on `k`.

**Questions:**

(Q1) How can I complete the code for my approach ?

(Q2) Are there better approaches to this problem (i.e. faster, vectorized/less `for` loops, GPU-assisted) and if yes, what are they?

Comment: Is there a typical number of columns for `M`. i.e. `n` ? Would `S` always have unique set of integers?

Comment: `n` should not be more than 8 or 9, if I am not mistaken. For `S`, one can assume `S = unique(M)`, i.e. all elements of `S` are already contained somewhere in `M`. All elements of `S` are distinct and their order does not matter. I hope I have understood your second question correctly.

Comment: @July: In most of your question `M` is the name for your input matrix, but in the example `M` is a possible solution, please rename it there. At least we know that the size of your solution is `numel(S)`, this allows to try approximations and stop if this size is reached. Could you provide an example data set?

Comment: @Daniel: oops, sry, fixed. Sure, I could provide a data set, if you tell me where to upload it and how big you want it to be.

Comment: For Q1 -- it's hard to know how to complete the code without seeing the code. Also, "complete the code" is a general question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: For Q2 -- I'd advise you to not optimize and first get some approach working. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: @July: I came across this idea to generate problems which have at least one solution: http://pastebin.com/AyGR6gkx, might be useful to test.

Comment: For a good vectorization scheme, I think you might need RAM that holds 0.5 Mil X 0.5 Mil data. Have you got anything close to it, maybe a cluster? :)

Comment: This involves checking `nchoosek(m,s)` combinations of rows, which is _a lot_. For `m = 5e5` and `s = 3` there are about `2e16` combinations. Even with only 1e-6 seconds for each combination, that's about 600 years

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments! It looks like I might have to redesign the problems from scratch to obtain something computable in reasonable time on reasonable hardware :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is a not-very-special case of [exact cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover). If you were working in C, I would suggest [Knuth's Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X), implemented with [bit arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) instead of [dancing links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) due to the apparent density of the instances with which you are concerned. I expect that MATLAB can accommodate you nearly as well.

As an integer, the set {1, 2, 5, 6} can be represented as 2**1 + 2**2 + 2**5 + 2**6. Then the intersection of two sets is represented as the [bitwise and](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitand.html) of their representations, and the union of two sets is the bitwise or. The empty set is 0. Unfortunately, for S = 100, you'll need to use two or more integers, which complicates life. After you take a set, you can detect intersections with other sets via a vectorized `bitand`.

Comment: A logical sparse matrix might be an alternative to implement it.

Comment: @Daniel If that's implemented the way that I expect, then the running time for intersection will drop from quadratic to linear, but word-parallelism won't be exploited. I expect the key improvement here in any case to be using Algorithm X with a good column order.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Knuth's Algorithm X, which, at least in theory, solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?
I assumed that the order of the rows in M matters (i.e. permutting 2 rows is another valid M).
This example gives you all the matrixes with 2 columns and 3 rows, where elements are all distinct and in {1,2,3,4,5,6}. However rows are a subset of {1,2,3,4,5,6} where the order does NOT matter. Not sure if this what you meant. If the order matters, we can add `perms` to get all possible permutations for each row returned by `nchoosek`.

I had to use a recursive function, so you would have to put it in a file:

```
function test()
    s = 1:6;
    n = 2;

    M_all = ProcessOneRow(s, n, {}, {});

    disp('All possilbe M:')
    M_all
end

function M_all = ProcessOneRow(s, n, cRows, M_all)

    %// find all possible rows for this level
    possibleRows = nchoosek(1:length(s), n);

    for t=1:size(possibleRows, 1)
        %// keep track of all rows so far
        cRows(end+1) = s(possibleRows(t,:));

        %// get elements remaining (remove this row)
        s_sub = s;
        s_sub(possibleRows(t,:)) = [];

        if isempty(s_sub)
            %// We found a new complete matrix M
            M = [];
            for p = 1:numel(cRows)
                M(p,:) = cRows{p};
            end
            M_all{end+1} = M;
        else
            %// Still not a complete M, so we process the rest
            M_all = ProcessOneRow(s_sub, n, cRows, M_all);
        end
        cRows(end) = [];
    end
end
```